# Passing MultipartFormDataInput between services

Tags: quarkus

I am working on a project where I need to upload some files and for that I am using MultipartFormDataInput as container for the files.
The bird-eye view of this construct is as follow
 
Frontend -> Gateway -> Service Module 
 
The Service module contains more than one functionality and one of them is the upload
I first implemented the upload of files in "Service module" and successfully tested it with Postman.
The signature of the method is as follow

```
@POST
@Path("{id}/files")
@Consumes(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response saveFiles(@PathParam("id") String id, @MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput input)
```

I then moved to the "Gateway" Service and implemented the part that should receive the code from the Frontend and the signature is as follow

```
@POST
@Path("{id}/files")
@Consumes(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response saveFiles(@PathParam("id") String id, @MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput input)
```

which is the same signature as the one in the "Service" module.

I tested it with PostMan and the Gateway correctly receives the files and the MultipartFormDataInput but passing it with the RestClient which code is following, the Service module now receives an empty MultipartForm.

Am I missing something or do I need to do things differently in order to pass the MultipartForm as I will surely have the same problem when trying to implement the code in the Frontend module.

```
@RegisterRestClient
@RegisterClientHeaders
@ClientHeaderParam(name = APPLICATION_NAME, value = "gateway")
@Path("/voters")
@RequestScoped
public interface VotersClient {
    @POST
    @Path("{id}/files")
    @Consumes(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    Response saveFiles(@PathParam("id") String id, @MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput input);
}
```

Comment: Which Quarkus RESTEasy extensions are you using?

Comment: I'm only using quarkus-resteasy-jsonb and quarkus-resteasy.
When you mentioned extensions, I added resteasy-multipart-provider just in case but to no avail